# Can I use Arduino nano's power straight for the micro motors or do I need to use drivers for a drone?

Tags: arduino

I haven't tried using nano as the primary source for the micro motors as I'm still planning for project. If possible please suggest me any motor driver with less weight or if using any MOSFET would be more efficient ( voltage 3.7-3.3 V)

Comment: Micromotor? Define what you mean when you say that as these terms have no real meaning. –

Comment: You _really_ shouldn't use the same power supply for digital stuff and for motors without a regulator in between.

Comment: If you want to build a drone, first study practical *existing* designs.  Little pager motors are typically run with small NFETs, but an Arduino board is rather heavy and unnecessary, projects that started that way have long since moved on to better choices.

Comment: Max power/pin is about 60 mW - it is very very very very unlikely that that is enough for any task. It is in any case very very unwise to drive any inductive device directly with a processor pin. Any MOSFET with a VGSth (gate minimum drive voltage) of under about 1.5V and suitable current & voltage ratings is liable to suit

Comment: If desired,  an Arduino can be replaced by a processor IC and support hardware appropriate to your system.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Datapoint only: [An Arduino Pro Mini](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Arduino-Pro-Mini-328-5V-16MHz-p-1443.html) weighs "under 2 grams" (they say) with dimensions 18 x 33 mm. Certainly one can manage smaller and lighter, but in many cases this is 'small enough'.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon typical all-up weight of a small drone is 15 grams or so.  2g grams while essentially providing nothing but the processor itself (ie still needing the radio, sensor, motor drive, etc all to be added) actually is a lot.  And then there's interconnect, which gets a lot heaver when you have to run all of those signals between boards.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Indeed. I had noted above " f desired, an Arduino can be replaced by a processor IC and support hardware appropriate to your system " -> the point of noting that (which could have been clearer {as ever}) was that even though it is "obvious", many people do not realise that the whole core functionality of an Arduino resides in and can be replaced by the "processor IC" alone. Which is also well correlated with what you are saying.

Answer (score 3):

The Atmega328p datasheet states that you can draw a maximum of 40mA per I/O pin, with a maximum of 200mA for the full device (you can drive around 4 I/O pins at max current, since the processor itself will still draw some additional current).  If you need more current than that, you'll need to use a MOSFET (for single direction on/off) or an H-bridge (for two direction on/off), or an ESC module (for brushless motors).

[datasheet, see page 313](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf#page=313)

Comment: The currents that you cited are "Absoluite maximum" ratings that must NEVER be used for desin purposes. ABS MAX ratings are ones below which the manufacturer guarantees the device will not be damaged. They do not guarantee that  it will operate correctly at these values or that it will not need to be reset or powered down before again working properaly again. || Values which should be used are "Typical" values - here found on page 364 in the [datasheet - p364(https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf#page=364). These are surprisingly high at 20 mA/pin. ...

Comment: ... For low drive a 20 mA load pulls the pin up by typically 0.7V and for high drive it pulls it down by about 0.8V. (Tgis varies with temperature, Vcc and load). 
It is though exceedingly unwise to drive a motor or inductive device with a processor pin directly.



https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf#page=364